# Ordering references with bracketed years in biblatex 2.7

Tags: biblatex

In `biblatex` version 2.5, bibliographic entries with the `YEAR` field in brackets in the `.bib` source were still sorted in the bibliography as if the field was without brackets. Cf. the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Peace on earth",
    YEAR = "1972",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "More peace on earth",
    YEAR = "[1974]",
    LOCATION = "London",
    PUBLISHER = "Music Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{lennon1972}\nocite{lennon1974}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is no longer the case with `biblatex` version 2.7. I don't know what determines their sorting anymore, but it seems like the entries with the `YEAR` field in brackets is always put first in the sorted list under that author.

[image]

What can I do to get the sorting behavior of `biblatex` version 2.5 back?

Comment: You can add a `sortyear` field:     `YEAR = "[1974]",
    SORTYEAR="1974",`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will sort according to the value of the field so biblatex 2.5 was incorrect in this case. It's rather strange to put the brackets in the field - that's a style issue which is better handled by some other field which shows that the year needs special formatting. If you really must do it this way, do it automatically with:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=year,
            match=\regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\z},
            final]
      \step[fieldset=sortyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

This automatically adds a `sortyear` field consisting of only the numeric contnents of the `year` field if the year field has literal brackets in the .bib. Since in the default biblatex sorting schemes, `sortyear` is used instead of `year` for sorting, this will get the sorting right without changing the `year` field.

Comment: Could you please clarify a couple of things for me? (1) biblatex 2.7 sorts based on the character ``[``? What did version 2.5 do? (2) What is the "it" that your suggestion command does? Or in other words, could you clarify with some prose what the command does?

Comment: I've added prose about what this does. I'd have to go back to the 2.5 code (well, actually the `biber` 1.5 code as biber does the sorting) to see what was happening but there have been some fairly substantial relevant internal changes in 2.6/1.6 to do with label* date fields. Biblatex shouldn't be auto-correcting sorting like you mention - that's too confusing in the long term. I suspect the behaviour you saw in 2.5 was an artefact and wasn't doing quite what you saw in general.

Comment: I get this error when adding your command: ``Runaway argument?
{ \maps [datatype=bibtex]{ \map { \step [fieldsource=year, match=\regexp \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \DeclareSourcemap.`` It seemed like it lacked a final ``}``, but adding that resulted in a ``Missing \begin{document}`` error.

Comment: Sorry, there was another typo in the example - corrected now.

Comment: I get this error now: ``! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.``

Comment: Are you sure? Cut and pasting your MWE and the corrected code above works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to remove the previous command with the typo from further down my preamble. It works.