# \DeclareSourcemap in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have used `\DeclareSourcemap` in `biblatex` for three things, cf. [Ordering references with bracketed years in biblatex 2.7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126511/ordering-references-with-bracketed-years-in-biblatex-2-7), [Abbreviate resolved abbreviations in authors' first names in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95331/abbreviate-resolved-abbreviations-in-authors-first-names-in-biblatex), and [Change US postal codes (CA) to AP stylebook abbreviations (Calif.) in bibliography (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142627/change-us-postal-codes-ca-to-ap-stylebook-abbreviations-calif-in-bibliograp).

As pointed out by moewe in a comment (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142665/9077), however, `\DeclareSourcemap` cannot be used more than once. I have tried to combine the three things I've used `\DeclareSourcemap` for into one command, as seen in the MWE below. The result, however, is that no. 1 does not work in combination with either no. 2 or 3. No. 2 and 3 work fine together, though. In the output below, where all three are used together, only no. 1 has any effect.

What do I need to do in order to take advantage of all three?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype = bibtex]{\map{
%% 1. Find year in brackets and sort them as if they were without brackets
    \step[fieldsource = year, 
        match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\z}, final]
    \step[fieldset = sortyear, fieldvalue = {$1}]
%% 2. Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
    \step[fieldsource = author,
        match = \regexp{\[[^]]+\]},
        replace = .]
%% 3. Change US postal codes such as 'MA' to 'StateMA'
    \step[fieldsource = location,
        match = \regexp{,\s*(MA|CA|NY)},
        replace = \regexp{,~\\State\{$1\}}]
    }}}
% then change 'StateMA' etc. to AP style abbreviations 'Mass.' etc.
\def\State#1{\csname State#1\endcsname}
\def\StateMA{Mass.}
\def\StateCA{Calif.}
\def\StateNY{N.Y.}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{western1889,
    AUTHOR = "Aug[ust] Western",
    TITLE = "Kurze darstellung des norwegischen lautsystems",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Phonetische Studien",
    YEAR = "1889",
    PAGES = "259--282",
    VOLUME = "2"}
@BOOK{lehiste1970,
    AUTHOR = "Ilse Lehiste",
    TITLE = "Suprasegmentals",
    YEAR = "1970",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge, MA",
    PUBLISHER = "The M.I.T. Press"}
@BOOK{hoff1946,
    AUTHOR = "Ingeborg Hoff",
    TITLE = "Skjetvem{\aa}let",
    YEAR = "1946",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    NUMBER = "1",
    PUBLISHER = "Jacob Dybwad",
    SERIES = "Skrifter utgitt av Det Norske Videnskaps-Akademi i Oslo. II. Historisk-filosofisk klasse. 1946"}
@INCOLLECTION{hoff1968,
    AUTHOR = "Ingeborg Hoff",
    BOOKTITLE = "Aurskog og Blaker",
    EDITOR = "[Eyvind Lillevold]",
    TITLE = "M{\aa}let i Aurskog og Blaker",
    YEAR = "[1968]",
    LOCATION = "[Aurskog og Blaker]",
    PAGES = "685--752",
    PUBLISHER = "Bygdeboknemnda for Aurskog og Blaker",
    VOLUME = "3"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best practice for Biber sourcemapping is as follows.

- Use `\DeclareSourcemap` only once. <sub>Starting from version 3.11 of `biblatex` you can actually use `\DeclareSourcemap` multiple times without bad side-effects. For compatibility reasons you probably want to stick to the one-sourcemap approach for now. I also think using only one can sourcemap help you keep track of all your manipulations in one place, so I still recommend it, but there are situations where multiple `\DeclareSourcemap` are a better solution.</sub>
- Put only those `\step`s forming a logical unit, i.e. those 'belonging' together - those doing the same thing, into the same `\map`. (In this example the `final` in one of the mapping commands prevents further execution of the following commands.)
- Put the `\map`s for the same `datatype` into the same `\maps` environment.

So here we get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{%% 1. Find year in brackets and sort them as if they were without brackets
      \step[fieldsource = year, 
          match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\z}, final]
      \step[fieldset = sortyear, fieldvalue = {$1}]
    }
    \map{%% 2. Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
      \step[fieldsource = author,
          match = \regexp{\[[^]]+\]},
          replace = .]
    }
    \map{%% 3. Change US postal codes such as 'MA' to 'StateMA'
      \step[fieldsource = location,
          match = \regexp{,\s*(MA|CA|NY)},
          replace = \regexp{,~\\State\{$1\}}]
    }
  }
}
% then change 'StateMA' etc. to AP style abbreviations 'Mass.' etc.
\newcommand{\State}[1]{\csname State#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\StateMA}{Mass.}
\newcommand{\StateCA}{Calif.}
\newcommand{\StateNY}{N.Y.}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{western1889,
    AUTHOR = "Aug[ust] Western",
    TITLE = "Kurze darstellung des norwegischen lautsystems",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Phonetische Studien",
    YEAR = "1889",
    PAGES = "259--282",
    VOLUME = "2"}
@BOOK{lehiste1970,
    AUTHOR = "Ilse Lehiste",
    TITLE = "Suprasegmentals",
    YEAR = "1970",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge, MA",
    PUBLISHER = "The M.I.T. Press"}
@BOOK{hoff1946,
    AUTHOR = "Ingeborg Hoff",
    TITLE = "Skjetvem{\aa}let",
    YEAR = "1946",
    LOCATION = "Oslo",
    NUMBER = "1",
    PUBLISHER = "Jacob Dybwad",
    SERIES = "Skrifter utgitt av Det Norske Videnskaps-Akademi i Oslo. II. Historisk-filosofisk klasse. 1946"}
@INCOLLECTION{hoff1968,
    AUTHOR = "Ingeborg Hoff",
    BOOKTITLE = "Aurskog og Blaker",
    EDITOR = "[Eyvind Lillevold]",
    TITLE = "M{\aa}let i Aurskog og Blaker",
    YEAR = "[1968]",
    LOCATION = "[Aurskog og Blaker]",
    PAGES = "685--752",
    PUBLISHER = "Bygdeboknemnda for Aurskog og Blaker",
    VOLUME = "3"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]

Comment: I understand - thanks for the pedagogical explanation! :) But as Oleg mentioned in a comment to my question, ``final`` doesn't seem to be needed at all. Any idea why it was there in the first place?

Comment: @Sverre I suppose the `final` was there because the PLK re-used some other sourcemap he had written before. While in *this instance* the final is not needed (I think), simply because if no match is found the replacement text will be empty and `sortyear` will be set to empty and discarded, it is in general not a bad idea to have a `final` in a place like this. Consider the case in which the second `\step` is not `\step[fieldset = sortyear, fieldvalue = {$1}]`, but `\step[fieldset = sortyear, fieldvalue = {Hi, Sverre}]` and compare the output with and without `final`.

Comment: Your comments about including ``final`` are taken to heart. It turned out that removing ``final`` triggered a lot of warnings about ``sortyear`` being empty.