# Remove brackets from cite commands in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I use brackets to fill out missing information in the bibliography. But when I include this information in citations in the text, these brackets should not appear. In the example below, the text should read

> As John Lennon wrote in 1970 ...

The bibliography should nevertheless still retain the brackets. (The custom `\citeauthorfullname` macro is something I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73819/9077)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfullname}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "This book was released with my Imagine album",
    YEAR = "[1970]"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
As \citeauthorfullname{lennon1970} wrote in \citeyear{lennon1970} \ldots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Turns out the album Imagine was released in 1971 ... Oops!

Comment: Shouldn't you have just `1971` etc. in the bib entry and use appropriate bib macros to format the list of references appropriately? (Rather than trying to take that stuff out in the text.) Apart from anything else, your current approach is inflexible - it is hard to change the style of the bibliography because you need to rewrite the bib entries.

Comment: Do you really want '([YYYY])'?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `sortname` and `sortyear` fields (in which, of course you give the year/name without brackets) and print those in `\citeauthorfullname` and `\citeyear`? Another approach (that is probably not applicable to names or more complex situations) is to input all data normally but add a flag `guessedyear` which causes `biblatex` to wrap the guessed year into brackets in the bibliography (this could be extended to other fields as well, it will fail for `Lennon, J[ohn]` and other partial insertions, though).

Comment: You should have a `sortyear` field for entries with a guessed year anyway; as it stands now they are sorted before all the other works by the same author. But printing the `sortyear` might have adverse effect - after all the `sortyear` might contains something like `1970-1` or worse things that one would not want to see in the document itself, the same goes for `sortname`. We could of course define a new field `bareyear` that gets the year without brackets and the like (it could even be populated via Biber's sourcemapping).

Comment: @moewe The fix for correctly sorting years within brackets is addressed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126511/ordering-references-with-bracketed-years-in-biblatex-2-7

Comment: Ahhh, I thought you had asked a question like that before, but I could not find it. What about the other ideas though? You could combine the answer there with a new `bareyear` field for example.

Comment: @moewe I didn't quite understand your suggestion on that point. But moreover, I'm usually at a loss what to do with suggestions, however good they might be, if they're not accompanied by a MWE. I'm a perpetual novice when it comes to LaTeX coding :)

Comment: Mhh, the idea was to create a new field `bareyear` that takes the year *without* brackets (while you would add brackets to the `year` field if need be) that could be used for in-text `\citeyear`. (In fact, you would not even have to populate that field yourself, just use the fix you linked to above) I hesitate to answer (with a MWE) though because I realise that this fix is only applicable to a specific field (`year` for example), one would have to create a new `bare...` field of each field one needs this functionality for.

Comment: @moewe Wouldn't it be sufficient to let ``\citeyear`` refer to the field ``sortyear`` instead? As I understood the solution to the question I link to, everything in the field ``year`` is copied into ``sortyear`` anyway, with possible brackets removed.

Comment: I thought about that as well (in my comment above), but the `sortyear` might contain more than just the year. In `biblatex-examples.bib`, for example, `knuth:ct:a`'s `sortyear` is `1984-1`. You would not want to have that printed. So you would have to restrict your (correct) usage of the `sortyear` field

Comment: @moewe I certainly don't have anything but actual years in my fields. So I would be happy to see a suggestion that does refer ``\citeyear`` to ``sortyear``. It's at least better than what I have now ...

Comment: OK, If you like, I can try to compose an answer, but it will only be able to deal with `year`s (and very easy cases of other fields). It will not be applicable to all the fields where you might supplement information in brackets, or only with heavy work.

Comment: @moewe I do use brackets in various fields, but I can't think of any other fields than ``author`` and ``year`` (i.e. ``sortyear`` in our case) where it is relevant now, since only ``\citeauthor`` (or my workaround ``\citeauthorfullname``) and ``\citeyear`` exist as cite commands.

Comment: Well, I just had to find out that there is no way to print the `sortyear` information from within `biblatex`. So your best bet is a `bareyear` field.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer but I wanted to elaborate on my comment.

To format the name, for example, you might try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfullname}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = {Lennon, John},
    TITLE = {This book was released with my Imagine album},
    YEAR = 1971}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\def\mybrack#1#2\@nil{#1[#2]}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamefirst[1]{%
    \mybrack#1\@nil}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
As \citeauthorfullname{lennon1970} wrote in \citeyear{lennon1970} \ldots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lennon, J[ohn] with standard bib entry]

Comment: This won't do the trick, I'm afraid, because this will put brackets in all first names in the bibliography. But as pointed out in my question, brackets are for filling out information that's literally missing in the source. In this case, the book would be published under the name ``J. Lennon``. Your suggested code will, however, also change the name to ``Lennon, J[ohn]`` when the source has the full name ``John Lennon``.

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how to implement a `bareyear` field that contains just the year with no additional brackets and can be used in `\citeyear` as well as a `bareauthor` field.

First, we have to make `biblatex` aware of our new fields via a `datamodel` file (save the following as `barefields.dbx` and locate it somewhere it can be found by LaTeX)

```
\ProvidesFile{barefields.dbx}[2014/04/02 allow for bracket-less fields]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{bareyear}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{bareyear}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{bareauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{bareauthor}
\endinput
```

We simply define a literal field `bareyear` that is valid for all entry types, as well as a name list `bareauthor`.

We populate the fields via

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=year,
            match=\regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\z},
            final]
      \step[fieldset=bareyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=sortyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\[(.+)\]}, final]
      \step[fieldset=bareauthor, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=bareauthor, match=\regexp{\[(.+)\]}, replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

just in the same manner as described by PLK in [Ordering references with bracketed years in biblatex 2.7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126563/35864). (The second part might be more buggy and break in some situations, the `year` thing should work fine though.)

What remains is to make `\citeyear` use `bareyear` and `\citeauthorfullname` use `bareauthor` if available

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{bareyear}
    {\printfield{year}}
    {\printfield{bareyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfullname}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifnameundef{bareauthor}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\printnames{bareauthor}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

You will notice that this will always print the author even if the `labelname` is actually set to the editor, but I think you will have to live with that. (I could not access `labelname` in the sourcemapping process because [presumably] at that point `biblatex` is not yet sure which name field to take as the `labelname`. Just an idea: You could create `bareauthor` and `bareeditor` fields and list them before the `author` and `editor` fields in the `\DeclareLabelname` command, thus `biblatex` would prefer the `bare...` versions to the "normal" names - then there would be no need to modify the cite commands.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear,datamodel=barefields]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=year,
            match=\regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\z},
            final]
      \step[fieldset=bareyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[fieldset=sortyear, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\[(.+)\]}, final]
      \step[fieldset=bareauthor, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=bareauthor, match=\regexp{\[(.+)\]}, replace=\regexp{$1}]
    }
  }
}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthorfullname}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifnameundef{bareauthor}
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\printnames{bareauthor}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{bareyear}
    {\printfield{year}}
    {\printfield{bareyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lennon1969,
  author  = {J[ohn] Lennon},
  title   = {Some work from 69 -- maybe Summer of},
  year    = {1969},
}
@book{lennon1970,
  author    = {J[ohn] Lennon},
  title     = {This book was released with my Imagine album},
  year      = {[1970]},
}
@book{lennon1971,
  author  = {J[ohn] Lennon},
  title   = {This is from 71},
  year    = {1971},
}
@book{lennon1972,
  author  = {John Lennon},
  title   = {This Really is by John Lennon},
  year    = {1972},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{barefields.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{barefields.dbx}[2014/04/02 allow for bracket-less fields]
\RequireBiber[3]

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{bareyear}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{bareyear}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{bareauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{bareauthor}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
As \citeauthorfullname{lennon1970} wrote in \citeyear{lennon1970} \ldots\ and in \citeyear{lennon1972}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In an attempt to simplify this, could I include that ``barefields.dbx`` file you suggested in the preamble with ``filecontents``?

Comment: @Sverre You can include it with `filecontents` as I did in the MWE above. You however cannot use the datamodel commands in the preamble themselves (while it might work with version 2.8, this is not supported with the upcoming version 2.9). But if you plan on using this more often, placing `barefields.dbx` in an accessible location is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a macro with the package `xstring`. I tried it for a while, but I couldn't get it work. Maybe someone else here is able to...

It's the function `\strDel`, with it you can remove a substring from your string:

```
\StrDel{Hello there J[ohn]}{[}[\result]%remove [ and save in \result
\StrDel{\result}{]}[\result]%remove ] and save in \result
```

The code above works, but sadly the following macro does not. It just prints out the content of `\citeyear{#1}`:

```
\newcommand{\citeyearp}[1]{%
\StrDel{\citeyear{#1}}{[}[\result]%
\StrDel{\result}{]}[\result]%
\result%
}
```